# How to make key-shortcuts of NSStatusItem work and accept key-shortcuts in not selected mode?

Tags: swift

I have a small issue with NSStatusItem which the key-shortcuts works if I click on the icon of app like this:

[image]

if you see when I click on icon of app the options of print and quit be presented the shortcuts of command + H and command + Q would work but if I lose the focus from the app icon like this:

[image]

in this case the shortcuts would not works any more! how can I define my shortcuts that works even if I not clicked on app icon.
By the way this app does not have window or icon on dock, all visibale item to user would the "figure.wave" button. this is the code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private lazy var statusItem: NSStatusItem = NSStatusItem()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "figure.wave", accessibilityDescription: "1")
        }
        
        let printHello: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "print Hello world!", action: #selector(printHelloAction) , keyEquivalent: "h")


        let quit: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q")

        let menu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(printHello)
        menu.addItem(quit)
        statusItem.menu = menu

    }
    
    @objc func printHelloAction() {
        print("Hello, world!")
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the normal behavior. Keyboard events are sent always to the frontmost application. How can the OS know that ⌘Q should quit your app and not Safari or other open applications?

Comment: That is right, how about we forget about "command + q" and make the other one some like this "command+option+h" can we do this?

Comment: As I said *Keyboard events are sent always to the frontmost application*. To receive a keyboard event in a non-frontmost app you have to create a global shortcut for example with help of [this library](https://github.com/Kentzo/ShortcutRecorder)

Comment: Thanks, Is this work so complicated that we need to use third party framework for that? I mostly found videos or website that they use a third party framework rather than showing the direct code to do by ourself.

Comment: Implementing a global shortcut is not trivial although the APIs are built-in.